# ie8 addClass and removeClass not working, jQuery1900969595128946837 added to the div instead of class

Tags: jquery

I have my footer slide up if the bottom of the page is reached, and also if an element is clicked. It works by adding / removing class `active` to / from the footer.

But it does not work in IE8. The class is not assigned, and whenever bottom of the page is reached, it goes up and then down, as if it has been clicked twice.

The class gets assigned ONLY if the page is at the bottom, and then  the page is refreshed so that it is automatically at the bottom on page refresh. But then the class never gets removed.

Again, the bottom line is adding / removing class is not working in IE8 in this case.

my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $('.footer .open').click();
   }
});

$('.footer').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $('.footer').removeClass('active');
        $('#page-footer').slideUp();

    }else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#page-footer').slideDown();

    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

i just noticed I get this added to the `footer` div in IE8.
`jQuery1900969595128946837` instead of class='active'. But it stays like that always, if I either slide up or down.

Any idea?

Comment: Your problem is here: `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()` not with `add\removeClass` debug your code. put `console.log` and `alert`s

Comment: What's your version of jQuery?

Comment: I don\t understand how this is an issue. If i just click the footer without scrolling the pages it still does not add / remove the class.

Comment: @Jack 1.7.1 I want to mention again, only IE8 is the problem. You think a later version will solve this?

Comment: try as `subPos = $("window").position();
    subPos = subPos.top;`

Comment: look at your status bar do you have any js error notification at left bottom of your ie browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could just Do:

```
$('.footer').on('click',function(){
        $('#page-footer').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I was going to answer the same! but actually it's not the issue! the issue is with as @gdoron mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Try [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of click:

```
$('.footer').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $('.footer').removeClass('active');
        $('#page-footer').slideUp();

    }else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#page-footer').slideDown();

    }
});
```

Comment: does not work. You said you wanted to give the same reply as Gordon. Can you give a different example of detecting page bottom?